# Firefox OS: Erro ao submeter app

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, app

Estou tentando validar meu app no marketplace do firefox. Porém, estou recebendo a seguinte noticia: Erro ao extrair o manifesto do arquivo zip.
Porém o manifest.webapp esta de acordo com a norma do firefox

```
  {
  "name": "Primeiro APP Firefox OS",
  "description": "meu primeiro app",
  "launch_path": "/run.html",
  "icons": {
    "60": "/img/icon-60-2.png",
    "128": "/img/icon-128.png"
  },
  "developer": {
    "name": "alex jose silva",
    "url": "http://www.alexjosesilva.com"
  },
  "default_locale": "Pt-br"
}
```

Algum sugestão de como posso corrigir isso ?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que aparece no relatorio de validação completo?

Comment: Em testes gerais: Erro ao extrair o manifesto do arquivo.zip

Comment: @alexjosesilva O Marcelo perguntou o que aparece ao clicar em **Ver o relatório de validação completo**

Comment: Só aparece essa informar no relatório completo: Erro ao extrair o manifesto do arquivo zip.

Comment: Os demais testes sem erro! Embora no firefox Simulador o app roda e passa no teste de validação!

Comment: Estou usuando o firefox 35 e rodando windows 8! Tem algum plugin ? o procedimento  anterior ???

Comment: Aqui esta um link para testar https://github.com/willemallan/tableless-firefox-os-example

Comment: Tenho de fazer alguma configuração adicional no firefox ???